# Promise is missing properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, spfx-webparts, typescript, pnpjs

When I try to create array, to put the results in the array, then I get the following error message:

```
const allItems : any [] = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").items.get();
```

> Type 'Promise<any[]>' is missing the following properties from type
> 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 16 more.ts(2740)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are missing `await` in your code. Try using below code:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";

// get all the items from a list
const items: any[] = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").items.get();
console.log(items);
```

**Reference**: [List Items - Basic Get](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#basic-get)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `await` in your code, use this instead:

```
const allItems : any [] = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").items.get();
```